# React error- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'children' of '_ref' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have used useEffect to fetch API & dispatch an action from inside it to update state. I am using context API, useReducer for state management and also react-router in this project.

In Header.js *as soon as* i import/use CartState and state variable (e.g. cart.length) then the app breaks down and items from api are not rendered and i get this error. In home.js also i am using state, but with only that part it does not give any error.
Below i am attaching two images, one with error and one where it is rendered when i remove CartState from header.js

Or you can see the *codesandbox* : https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-fast-297j3h?from-embed=&file=/

[Website picture when CartState removed from header.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ6OB.png)

[Error message - website picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Vv1.png)

Please tell me what is the issue here and what should be done.

**index.js file:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import GlobalContext from './context/GlobalContext'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <GlobalContext>
        <App />
      </GlobalContext>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**App.js:**

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Components/Home/Home'
import Cart from './Components/Cart'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/cart" exact element={<Cart/>}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**GlobalContext.js:**

```
const CartContext = createContext();
const GlobalContext = ({children}) => {
  const initialState ={
    products: [],
    cart: []
  };
useEffect( ()=>{
    const fetchData = async ()=> {
      const res = await axios('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
      
      const resAdd = res.data.map((item)=> ({...item, inStock: faker.helpers.arrayElement([0,2,5,9,20]), fastDelivery: faker.datatype.boolean() }));
      
      dispatch({type: 'API_CALL_SUCCESS', payload: resAdd});
      // console.log(initialState);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [] )
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState );
  console.log(state);
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
        {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default GlobalContext;
export const CartState = () => {
  return useContext(CartContext);
};
```

**Header.js** (part of the code)

```
import CartState from "../context/GlobalContext";
const Header = () => {
  const {
    state: { cart },
    dispatch,
  } = CartState();

return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" style={{ height: 100 }}>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand>
          <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <FormControl
          className="m-auto"
          style={{ width: 500 }}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search here the product you want"
        />

        <Nav>
          <Dropdown
          // alignRight
          >
            <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success">
              <FaShoppingCart color="white" fontSize="25px" />
              <Badge>
                {cart.length}
              {/* 1 */}
              </Badge>
            </Dropdown.Toggle>
```

**Home.js:**

```
import { CartState } from '../../context/GlobalContext'
import SingleProduct from '../SingleProduct';
import './styles.css'
import Filters from '../Filter/Filters';

const Home = () => {
  const {state: {products}, } = CartState();
  console.log(products);
  
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <Filters />
      <div className="productContainer">
        {products.map( (item)=> 
          <SingleProduct prod = {item} key = {item.id} />
         )}
      </div> 
    </div>
  )
}
export default Home
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify below code line in `Header.js` file.

Actual:
`import CartState from "../context/GlobalContext";`

Expected/correct:
`import {CartState} from "../context/GlobalContext";`

Reason: `CartState` is not a default export.

Answer (score 0):

In `Header.js`:

```
import CartState from '../context/GlobalContext';
```

this part of your code is wrong because **you didn't export default your CartState function** so you should import it like:

```
import {CartState} from "../context/GlobalContext";
```